# Android custom SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, simpleadapter

I'm trying this [example](http://dustinbreese.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-listview-with-alternating.html) for creating a simpleAdapter for a ListView. So, I got all created but when I change this line

```
List<Movie> movies = getData2();
ListAdapter adapter = new MovieListAdapter(this, movies, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{Movie.KEY_NAME, Movie.KEY_YEAR}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
```

I got this error:

The constructor is undefined

`MovieListAdapter(ImdbApiActivity, List<Movie>, int, String[], int[])`

It's the same example, I've just changed Cars for Movies. I know that this example is from 2009, my target is 2.1 on my project. Is there a incompatibility between versions or is there an error?

My simpleadapter class looks like this:

```
public class MovieListAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List < Movie > movies;

    private int[] colors = new int[] {
        0x30ffffff, 0x30808080
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MovieListAdapter(Context context, List <? extends Map < String, String >> movies,
        int resource,
        String[] from,
        int[] to) {
        super(context, movies, resource, from, to);
        this.movies = (List < Movie > ) movies;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Is there an error i'm missing? which is the "modern" way to achieve this?

**Edit:** Neither changing the context parameter or the List worked for this example. My Movie class extends from Hashmap. Any other idea? thanks!

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Movie extends HashMap {

    public String year;
    public String name;
    public static String KEY_YEAR = "year";
    public static String KEY_NAME = "name";

    public Movie(String name, String year) {
        this.year = year;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(Object k) {
        String key = (String) k;
        if (KEY_YEAR.equals(key))
            return year;
        else if (KEY_NAME.equals(key))
            return name;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check that you are passing right context or not. It looks like you are passing wrong context.

Comment: I think,List<? extends Map<String, String>> movies in your custom adapter constructor parameter should be changed to List<Movies> movies. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be problem in the parameter of your custom adapter class constructor.

You have defined it as `List<? extends Map<String, String>>` movies where you are passing `List<Movies>` object from the activity.That is why it is telling you,such constructor is not defined.

Try changing parameter of constuctor to `List<Movies> movies`,that would resolve your problem,i think!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
`ListAdapter adapter = new MovieListAdapter(this, movies, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{Movie.KEY_NAME, Movie.KEY_YEAR}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});`
```

to

```
`ListAdapter adapter = new MovieListAdapter(YourClass.this, movies, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{Movie.KEY_NAME, Movie.KEY_YEAR}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});`
```

because `this` may be referencing to the different instance.

`YourClass.this` is a reference to an instance of the `YourClass.class`. You can also send  context returned by [`getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)